# How to send POST variables to External URL ?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm making a shopping cart. I would like to save the order before going to the payment gateway. 
My payment gateway requires me to send a POST to external address but not how to do it from a controller action.

```
public function executeBuy(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers('Url');

  // save the order
  $this->order = new Order();
  $this->save
  //etc....

  //go to TPV Payment gateway
  $dsAmount       = (float)$order->getPriceWithShipping() * 100;
  $dsOrder        = (int)$order->getId() * 400;
  $dsMerchantCode = (int)sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_code');
  $dsCurrency     = (int)sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_currency');
  $dsMerchantURL  = url_for('cart/ipn', true, array(
    'sf_culture' => $this->getUser()->getCulture(),
  ));
  $options = array(
    'Ds_Merchant_Amount'            => $dsAmount,
    'Ds_Merchant_Currency'          => $dsCurrency,
    'Ds_Merchant_Order'             => $dsOrder,
    'Ds_Merchant_Titular'           => $order->getAddress()->getCustomer()->getNameAndLastName(),
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode'      => $dsMerchantCode,
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL'       => $dsMerchantURL,
    'Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature' => $digest,
    'Ds_Merchant_Terminal'          => $dsCurrency
  );

  //how to send post $options variables to external url?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cURL to post data](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl):

```
//set POST variables
$dsMerchantURL = url_for('cart/ipn', true, array(
  'sf_culture' => $this->getUser()->getCulture(),
));

$options = array(
  'Ds_Merchant_Amount' => urlencode($dsAmount),
  'Ds_Merchant_Currency' => urlencode($dsCurrency),
  'Ds_Merchant_Order' => urlencode($dsOrder),
  'Ds_Merchant_Titular' => urlencode($order->getAddress()->getCustomer()->getNameAndLastName()),
  'Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode' => urlencode($dsMerchantCode),
  'Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL' => urlencode($dsMerchantURL),
  'Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature' => urlencode($digest),
  'Ds_Merchant_Terminal' => urlencode($dsCurrency)
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($options as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'& ');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $dsMerchantURL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($options));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I need open the url with post variables! Like tag form and submit but withouth html

Comment: How do I get open in the same window?

Comment: In fact, `url_for` will open the link in the same window if you don't specify anything about `target` parameter.

Comment: my url to go is not $dsMerchantURL. Is $url=sfConfig::get('app_tpv_url'); But this is not the problem. If I put curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->getContext()->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('User-Agent')); appear response html but the cpu is overloaded for httpd service. I tried using CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and no result!

Comment: The other problem is css of the bank gateway not working. The images are relative url and fail on javascript. Is there any way to change the url to go directly to the bank gateway with post vars?

Comment: Did you check what return `$this->getContext()->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('User-Agent')` ? Css & js from the bank is an other problem, right? The way to send post data to the bank works, right?

Comment: $this->getContext()->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('User-Agent') returns 
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19

Comment: yes. my problem is go to the bank gateway before going to my custom action

Comment: So you might post an other question then :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14345/discussion-between-mauro-and-j0k)

Answer (score 0):

at our website (bpremium.com) we run our payment system over ajax, our website sends commands like "create sale" or "update quantity" over webservices to particular url's and those url's record the current state of your shopping cart and store the sale id in the session.

then when we get to the TPV, we execute a webservice to grab the html for the form, generated, signed and hashed, ready to go with a single button press.

this technique is great for high speed, cause you dont need to keep redirecting and forcing the user to wait, it's a lot less heavy and means you can just open the TPV into a window, fill it in and the merchantURL will catch the POST data from the TPV gateway when it succeeds or fails.