# TYPO3 external authentication server

Tags: oauth, typo3, typo3-9.x

I would like to use an external authentication service for frontend users which works with a REST API.

The things I made so far:

- An authenticationService class in a TYPO3 extension, which gets loaded with priority 90. It seems to work when debugging and has the (still empty) functions getUser, authUser and getGroups
- A PHP authentication test script. When provided with username and pw, it produces the URL to test with cURL in terminal. JSON userdata gets send back.

What is the way to get the JSON in my authenticationService class? Should I use cURL directly like [How to send POST variables to External URL ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485834/how-to-send-post-variables-to-external-url)
Or are there core methods for this I should use?

And I guess I need to map the JSON to a temporary frontend user record to give the authenticated user access to certain pages etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using TYPO3 8 or 9, you can use the class `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\RequestFactory` to do HTTP requests. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Http/Index.html for more on that.

TYPO3 frontend authentication always needs an entry in the `fe_users` table. So you will have to insert a user in that table. You can then either leave the user there for the next time it logs in or create a cleanup routine (for example using a scheduled task) to cleanup old users.